# Reinitialize an existing git repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I have the following situation:
there is a Gitlab repo, which has been initialized with the default branch `XXX` instead of `master`.
The branch `XXX` already has some commits there.

The target is to reinitialize the repo where the `master` branch is the default and empty one. The existing changes need to be in a feature branch, which should be branched from the empty `master`.

update:
in order to explain the target better,
the current state:

```
1-2-3-...-n
^
xxx
```

the desired state:

```
master
▼
1
 \
  2-3-...-n
  ^
  xxx
```

it also makes sense to add that the situation allows to squash all existing commits in the branch `xxx` to one "initial" if it is required.

Comment: Sounds like you shoud just rename the branch. To the extent that "reinitialize" is well-defined, it would erase your commits.

Comment: "branched from the empty master" You cannot branch from an empty anything. There is no such thing as an empty branch so the question makes no sense. It seems like you don't know what a branch is? It is the name of a _commit_.

Comment: @matt, "from master, which does not have any commits, related to the feature" is that clearer to you? Any really useful question? or just _questions make no sense_ ?

Comment: @matt After `git init`, there will be a branch named `main` that doesn't point to a commit. Would you call this "empty"? Or do I misunderstand the state of the repo immediately after `git init`?

Comment: In the top graph, I'm guessing commit 1 is not an empty commit but has changes in it. From your desired picture in the bottom graph, it looks like you want commit 1 to be an empty commit with `master` pointing to that, and then perhaps commit 2 in the bottom graph is basically the changes that commit 1 in the top graph had? (And then bottom 3 is like top 2, etc.) Is that correct?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice "Or do I misunderstand" Yes. That isn't actually a branch. It's termed an "unborn branch", but that doesn't make it a branch. (Just as a squash merge is not a merge.) `HEAD` is configured to point to _refs/heads/main_, but there is no main branch yet; it's just something ready so that you have somewhere to make a first commit. It's sort of a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: @matt How would the OP create such an "unborn branch" manually? Is there a way without doing `git init`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't think so, and it wouldn't do any good to do so. You can't "branch off it".

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: `git checkout --orphan` and `git switch --orphan` put you in this special "on a branch that does not exist" state. The *next* commit you make, while in this state, *creates* this branch; the commit you create, while in this state, has no parent, so it is a root commit. Note that this state is fragile: checking out any other branch by name destroys it and you must start over with another `git switch --orphan`.

Comment: This state also isn't useful for solving the original problem as stated, since creating a new root commit creates a commit whose history is not related to the original history. Or, as they may sometimes say in Maine, "you can't get thar from here."

Answer (score 3):

To put it visually, it sounds like you want to go from this:

```
o---o---o
        ^
        master
```

To this:

```
o---o----o
^        ^
master   feature
```

However, you also said:

> The existing changes need to be in a feature branch, which should be branched from the empty master.

In Git, there's no concept of an "*empty*" branch; a branch is a pointer to the last of a sequence of commits. This means that you have to point `master` to the first commit in the repository (i.e. the *root commit*).

Here's how you do it:

```sh
# Create the 'feature' branch pointing to the commit currently referenced by 'master'
git branch feature master

# Checkout the 'master' branch, if you haven't already
git switch master

# Reset 'master' to the root commit
git reset --hard master~2
```

Alternatively, you could get rid of the `master` branch for the time being, and simply recreate it later when you want to "merge" `feature` into `master`.

Here's one quick way of doing it as [suggested by @tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69271127/reinitialize-an-existing-git-repository/69271324#comment122434910_69271127):

```sh
# Rename 'master' to 'feature'
git branch -m master feature
```

At this point, you'd just have `feature`:

```
o---o---o
        ^
        feature
```

Merging `feature` into `master` then becomes simply a matter of creating the `master` branch on the same commit as `feature`:

```sh
git branch master feature
```

Which would look like this:

```
o---o---o
        ^
        feature, master
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response. Actually, there is no `master` branch in the repo at all, just a feature one `xxx`. I have added visualisation of the current and target states.

Comment: What is the state of `master` when you run `git init`? Would you consider this an "empty branch" since there are no commits for it to point to? I think this is the state that the OP wants.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Good question. In a brand new repo, there are no branches. You can see it yourself by running `git show-ref` right after `git init`. A branch named according to the `init.defaultBranch` setting will then be created upon the first commit.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can just create a feature branch at the current `XXX`:

```
git checkout -b feature XXX
```

To create a new master branch, use the `--orphaned` flag:

```
git checkout --orphaned master
git rm -rf .
```

The second command is necessary in order to clean up the working directory.

### Aside

While I use feature branches for my work in existing projects, I often will make the first few commits of a new project directly to master. This is often where I'm just generating all the boilerplate for a new project in the current framework, so there isn't really a need for the typical code review process that my teams use.

Comment: `git checkout --orphan`, not `--orphaned`. Using `git switch --orphan` obviates the need for the `git rm -rf .` step. (It's a small inconsistency between the newfangled switch and the old checkout!)

Comment: Also, re the aside: I like to make a new repository with just a README or similar. I think this is good practice. GitHub encourage this by pushing people to create their GitHub repos with one initial commit with files like this, too.

Answer (score 0):

So what I've finally done:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git commit .gitignore
git checkout -b XXX
git commit <...all the rest...>
```

Sure, that way does not preserve the previous history and it's not the elegant one,  however as I've already said, in my case, the state of the repo allows to squash all existing commits in the branch `xxx` to one.